# Laravel PHP 4: Trying to delete 'null' photo generates 'Trying to get property of non-object' error

Tags: php, laravel-4

I tried an experiment earlier by allowing an admin user to replace an image that was already uploaded to the database.  As a test, I allowed for submission of a 'blank' or 'empty' photo to be uploaded.  After the 'blank' photo was uploaded, I then tried to delete it but I keep getting a 'Trying to get property of non-object' error.

**Controller:**

```
public function destroy($albumId, $photoId)
{
    $this->photo->delete($photoId);
    return \Redirect::route("gallery.album.show", array('id' => $albumId));
}
```

EDIT:

**routes.php:**

```
Route::delete('gallery/album/{albumid}/photo/{photoid}/edit', array('as'=>'delete_photo', 'uses'=>'EditPhotosController@destroy'));
```

**View:**

```
/* 
Form code in here 
*/

{{ link_to_route('delete_photo', 'Delete Photo') }}
```

The problem was originally that my application was looking for the original 'file path' name to delete the original photo but now that the 'file path' name is currently null, it can't match on that name and therefore won't delete it.

EDIT: I'm thinking this might actually be a routing issue.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: Can we see the actual error? Where is `$this->photo` set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with this.

First, you're creating a route with an HTTP `DELETE` method. Links on their own make `GET` requests, not `DELETE` requests.

Usually you'll use a bit of javascript to submit a hidden form with a `_method` param set to `DELETE` to the URL in the `href` of the clicked link. [**jquery-ujs**](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) contains this funcitonality, but you can do it with much less code.

The next problem is you're not specifying the `albumid` or `photoid` params on the link

```
{{ link_to_route('delete_photo', 'Delete Photo', [ 'albumid' => $album->id, 'photoid' => $photo->id ]) }}
```

Finally, a route such as

```
DELETE /gallery/album/{albumid}/photo/{photoid}/edit
```

isn't the most RESTful. The `DELETE` should be made against the resource

```
DELETE /gallery/album/{albumid}/photo/{photoid}
```

Fixing the route params may fix your issue, but right now you have too much wrong and haven't provided a detailed error to give you more specifics.